# Adding polling mechanism in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polling

I have this javascript code:

```
function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/viewarrived'
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  });
}
```

My question is how do I add a polling mechanism so that it refreshes the data in a given interval?

Comment: add a self calling timeout interval in case of failure

Comment: By putting the data in the $scope the view will refresh itself when data change. otherwise you can use $watch in controller to watch a change on variable(s) and call a function.  Explain what did you want to do to get more precise help

Comment: I want the data to change automatically in the view when it changes in the database, and I would like to use a polling mechanism ($timeout) to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http, $interval)
{
   $scope.posts = [];

   $interval(function() {
        $http({method: 'GET', 
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/viewarrived'
        }).
        success(function(data){
            $scope.posts.push(data);
        })
   }, 1000);
}
```

It will be good to check the $interval svc:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I have added the suggested part, but now it adds an empty line every second, no changes in the data even when changes occur in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to check your data in success function, then to push it in $scope.post array, otherwise you will have unwanted element in $scope.posts array

Comment: I think my function does not return data, even though it should. This is the code currently:

Comment: function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http, $interval)
{

$http({method: 'GET', 
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/viewarrived'})
.success(function(data)
{
$scope.posts = data; // response data 
});

 

$interval(function() {
        $http({method: 'GET', 
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/viewarrived'
        }).
        success(function(data){
   $scope.posts = [];
            $scope.posts.push(data);
        })
}, 1000);